# Inserir dados no Active Directory via SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, active-directory

Estou trabalhando com integração entre Sql Server e o Active Directory. Já consigo importar informações do AD através de scripts. Gostaria de saber se é possível o contrário, através de comandos insert, inserir informações nos usuários do AD. Por exemplo, todos os usuários do AD estão sem o cargo cadastrado. Por um comando de insert no Sql Server consigo inserir as informações direto no campo correspondente no AD?

Comment: A resposta necessariamente tem que abranger apenas o SQL Server ou você aceitaria alguma alternativa em outra plataforma como o C#, por exemplo?

Comment: A princípio em SQL Server que é o que estamos usando no momento. A menos que não seja possível ou não muito adequado usar o SQL Server.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez pode me mostrar por gentileza a alternativa de inserção pelo c# então? Sabe me dizer como inserir por prompt de comando também, de repente criando um arquivo .bat?

Answer (score 3):

> **Aviso**: Conforme combinado com o autor da pergunta, esta resposta não se destina a responder exatamente o que foi pedido, e sim em fornecer alternativas para a manipulação de dados do Active Directory utilizando outras linguagens e plataformas.

Inserir informações pelo SQL Server no Active Directory poderia constituir prática insegura, com resultados imprevisíveis. Portanto, o recurso não foi habilitado. O que é possível fazer pelo SQL Server é obter informações a nível de consulta.

Sendo assim, existe ainda a possibilidade de inserção de informações usando métodos alternativos, em aplicativos escritos em linguagens como C# e VBScript.

[Há um artigo bem grande no CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C) em que são explicadas várias funcionalidades que podem ser implementadas para realizar várias tarefas de inserção.

Para VBScript e `BAT`, [Existe este site com centenas de exemplos](http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/adminscripts/) para as mais variadas tarefas.

Comment: Muito bom! Obrigado @Cigano

Comment: o Link já não se encontra mais ativo: https://www.activexperts.com/network-monitor/windowsmanagement/adminscripts/